# Enum and a function that returns the month name as a string

Tags: c, enums, switch-statement

This is the exercise:

> Write  a   function    called `monthName()`    that    takes   as  its argument    a   value   of  type `enum month` (as   defined in  this    chapter)    and returns a   pointer to  a   character   string containing   the name    of  the month.  In  this    way,    you can display the value   of  an  `enum month` variable   with    a   statement   such    as:
>
> `printf("%s\n", monthName(aMonth));`

I wrote my version and got the output I expected. However, I am sure that there must be a much better way to implement this without having to use a switch statement with one case for each month. How can I write this function with better design?

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum month { January = 1, February, March, April, May, June, 
        July, August, September, October, November, December };

char *monthName(enum month m){
    switch (m) {
        case January:
            return "January";
            break;
        case February:
            return "February";
            break;
        case March:
            return "March";
            break;
        case April:
            return "April";
            break;
        case May:
            return "May";
            break;
        case June:
            return "June";
            break;
        case July:
            return "July";
            break;
        case August:
            return "August";
            break;
        case September:
            return "September";
            break;
        case October:
            return "October";
            break;
        case November:
            return "November";
            break;
        case December:
            return "December";
            break;
        default:
            return "Not a valid month";
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    enum month aMonth = 1;

    printf("%s\n", monthName(aMonth));

    aMonth = 2;
    printf("%s\n", monthName(aMonth));

    aMonth = 6;
    printf("%s\n", monthName(aMonth));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The below answers look like what you want.  I consider starting your enum at 0 if possible, though, to simplify the addressing in the array and not wasting the 0th position with a non-month.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons By convention, months are numbered from 1 to 12. Ignoring that convention may confuse the reader, and risks off-by-one errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a simple lookup table, since the enum begin with 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum month { January = 1, February, March, April, May, June, 
        July, August, September, October, November, December };

const char *months_str[] = {
    "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
    "August", "September", "October", "November", "December", NULL
};

const char *monthName(enum month m) {
    if(m < January || m > December)
        return "Invalid month";

    return months_str[m-1];
}

int main(void)
{
    enum month aMonth = 1;

    printf("%s\n", monthName(aMonth));

    aMonth = 2;
    printf("%s\n", monthName(aMonth));

    aMonth = 6;
    printf("%s\n", monthName(aMonth));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems much more readable. May I ask why you add `NULL` as the last element of `months_str[]` ?

Comment: I end the array with `NULL` out of habit and out of convention. The `argv` array that contains the command line arguments in the `main` functions also is `NULL` terminated. The C Standard uses this technique, so I use that technique as well.

Comment: OK. Does it make much of a difference having or not having it? Upsides or downsides?

Comment: In this case it does not make any difference. Like I said, I put the `NULL` out of habit, so you can omit that if you want.

Answer (score 5):

You can create an array containing the strings and use the enum to index into it.

```
const char *monthNames[] = { "Not a valid month", "January", "February", "March", 
                             "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", 
                             "October", "November" "December" };

const char *monthName(enum month m)
{
    if (m < 1 || m > 12) {
        return monthNames[0];   // string for invalid month
    } else {
        return monthNames[m];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The switch is fine (but drop the `break`s after `return`, they're unreachable noise), but an array can be simpler.

In C99 and up, you can use the enumerated symbols to make it super-clear what is going on (and in theory make the source code order of the strings irrelevant):

```
const char *monthName(month m)
{
    static const char * const names[] = {
      [January] = "January",
      [February] = "February",
      ... and so on ...
   };
   return names[m];
}
```

The array is `static` to only initialize it once, and of course `const` since it doesn't change. It's inside the function to avoid littering the top-level space with names that are only used inside that function anyway.

You *could* also use this with a less optimized enumeration, but of course at the cost of memory. `int a[] = { [99] = 4 };` is still an array of 100 integers.

Comment: Enumerated symbols? I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @AregSarvazyan I meant the use of symbolic names inside the string array initializer expression, the  `[January] =` parts.